# How to refresh Related records & get the latest Count in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, childrelationship, imperativeapex

I have a LWC Component added on Case object. Purpose of the component is to Change Ownership of the records and updates other fields on Case object. Once Ownership is changed, I have trigger which automatically creates Case Comments records. So for each ownership change, new Case Comment Records gets created.

**Problem:** When I navigate from LWC to Case record Page, with **getRecordNotifyChange()** I can see updated values in Case fields but I could not see updated count of Case Comment records in Case Comments Related objects
**(Looks like only Case Records get refreshed not their Related Child Records)**. In order to see latest Count of Case Comment, I have to navigate to Case Comments or refresh the screen.

Below is the sample Code:

```
    handleSave(event) {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => {
        element.reportValidity();
    });
    changeOwnership({
            userId: this.userId
        })
        .then(result => {
            if (result === 'Success') {
                // To refresh the page
                getRecordNotifyChange([{
                    recordId: this.casesId
                }]);
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: this.casesId,
                        objectApiName: 'Case',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                });

                
            } else if (result === 'Error') {

            }

        })
        .catch(error => {});
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though getRecordNotifyChange() should update the cache but you can also try setting a timeout using old way to refresh the related components. Try with both settimeout and without. You can also try putting this in promise received from navigation.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Hi, I am using LWC not aura

Comment: You can still use it in JS

Comment: I tried by setting with timeout and it works as expected. thank you so much for the help!